# Applying function to Column

Tags: dataframe, rust, lambda, rust-polars

Is there a simple way to apply a function to a Polars `DataFrame` in Rust?

If my function and dataframe is the following for example:

```
fn double(x:i32) -> i32 {
    x*2
}

let s0 = Series::new("id", &[1, 2, 3]);
let s1 = Series::new("cost", &[10, 20, 30]);
let mut df = DataFrame::new(vec![s0, s1])?;
```

Here I'd like to do something that looks like:

```
df.apply("cost", |x| double(x))
```

Using pandas, I achieve the same with:

```
df["cost"] = df["cost"].apply(lambda x: double(x))
```

I'd love to know the equivalent way to apply a function over a column like this!

Comment: Something like `df.column("cost")?.i32()?.apply(double)`

Comment: Thank you this got me there in the end. I used this line above with replace:
```let df = df.replace("cost", df.column("cost")?.i32()?.apply(double));```

Comment: Found what I believe to be a more elegant solution, closing this now.
```df.apply("cost", |x| x.i32().unwrap().apply(double))?;```

Answer (score 0):

This might work ...

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let s0 = Series::new("id", &[1, 2, 3]);
    let s1 = Series::new("cost", &[10, 20, 30]);
    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![s0, s1]).unwrap().lazy();

    let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::UInt32);

    let new_df = df.with_column(
        col("cost")
            .alias("new_cost")
            .map(|x| Ok((&x * 2i32).into_series()), o),
    );

    println!("{:?}", new_df.clone().collect());
}
```

Comment: Would this incur extra memory overhead if I needed to apply multiple operations due to cloning?

Comment: @Sam My understanding with LazyFrames is, that the system will optimize all your operations when you finally need the data. In your case if you apply multiple operations (e.g. “df.with_column( ... “) then the system (polars) will minimize the memory footprint needed. E.g., if you first blow up your df (add ~30 columns) and at the end you only need the last column polars will do its best to just give you the results and not actually inflate / deflate  your df while doing so.